# PHP htag from h6 to h1 and getting array from zero and up in one loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I got this code here:

```
$aNames = array("Band1","Band2","Band3","Band4","Band5","Band6");

sort($aNames);

for($i = count($aNames); $i > 0; $i-- ) {
        echo "<h" .$i." align='center'>" . $aNames[$i-1] ." Is insane</h".$i.">";
}
```

it works. this code shows all the bands from h6 to h1 (from small to big) 
and for getting the names out of the array from 0 to 5 it uses the same variable but then puts -1 after it. Is there anyone that can tell me why i had to do $i-1 so it would go "reversed" from 0 to 5? Because i dont really get it how that works.

Comment: it went reversed because you started with `$i = 6` and performed a *decrementation* (`$i--`) after each iteration.

Comment: It's because arrays are zero-indexed. If you just started with the result of `count()`, you'd try to access `$aNames[6]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: You must've used `$i-1` as index because there's 6 items (what `count()`) returns but **arrays start at 0** (therefore the index `6` does not exists in your array)

Comment: @AymDev I get that, it used $1-1 as index so it would start at 5 because the array starts from 0. But you mean that the array automatically always starts counting at zero?

Comment: Did the array went reversed here or did it just started counting at zero automatically? more like what i ment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that arrays are **zero-indexed**, So when you use `count($aName)` it returns **6** but on your existing array there is nothing like `$aName[6]`, So to access the values of your `$aName` from then **last to first** you've to use `$i-1`. Hope this helps to understand it now.

**But with your existing code-** first of all where you used `for()` loop, you've do some refactoring like `count($aName)` the array length only once not in `for()` loop e.g

```
$aNames = array("Band1","Band2","Band3","Band4","Band5","Band6");
sort($aNames);
$count = count($aNames); // see the change here
for($i = $count; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
        echo "<h" .$i." align='center'>" . $aNames[$i-1] ." Is insane</h".$i.">";
}
```

and You can also use index based array to avoid `$i-1` way. Just use array like this format to keep track. Like as

```
$aNames = array(1=>"Band1",2=>"Band2",3=>"Band3",4=>"Band4",5=>"Band5",6=>"Band6");
```

*Apart From your existing solution*.You can easily do that using a `foreach()` without using any kind of `$i-1`. Just need to `krsort()` and `foreach()`

```
<?php

$aNames = array(1=>"Band1",2=>"Band2",3=>"Band3",4=>"Band4",5=>"Band5",6=>"Band6");
krsort($aNames);
foreach($aNames as $i=>$v){
    echo "<h" .$i." align='center'>" . $aNames[$i] ." Is insane</h".$i.">";
}
```

Comment: Thanks i get it. I just didnt know that the array will always start at zero. For some reason i thought that it whent reversed and that it started counting down from 5 because the variable $i also went -1. But that was not the case.

Comment: @kamsrra, Yeah you got it now. Glad it helps you somehow. Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing `$i-1` does not reverse the array. Arrays are zero indexed so 0 is the first item. `$aNames` has 6 items, that means you could get the values using `$aNames[0]`...`$aNames[5]`

If you would write `$aNames[$i]` instead, your code would try to access `$aNames[6]` on the first iteration which will give an `Undefined offset: 6`

In this case you want the value of `$i` for `<h1>...<h6> etc` and the `$i-1` to get the right index for `$aNames[0]...$aNames[5]`.

Note that using [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) in `sort($aNames);` does not change anything for the current data because it is already sorted.